Is this layout alright for the +5V rails?
From my understanding servo motors are pretty noisy and you shouldn't connect power to other components through a servo motor. I was wondering if this layout is OK or the servo motors will still affect the +5V power line?




You should also show the ground plane. If it's a double sided board then some of the tracks on the blue layer should easily be minimized if the GP is on that layer. I see at least 2 tracks that can be wholly on the red layer.

I’d just run the 5V rail for the servos as a horz track from J1 to J3.  Or maybe a bit copper fill? Why are you doing some crazed star network? Generally the track work needs a bit more thought - it looks like it was autorouted.
